# Is there a difference between font-weight bold and 700 when using webfonts?

Tags: css, fonts

I recently heard (and actually I don't much believe) that when you define @font-face with `font-weight` eg `700` and you use somewhere in CSS `font-weight: bold` that the browser may render that `font-weight` itself using faux bold type. Is there really such a difference between `700` and `bold` in such case?

So what I'm asking is: given such definition

```
@font-face {
  font-family: SampleFont;
  src: ...;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

will all browsers (according to specification) use specified file for `SampleFont` in following cases?

```
.case1 { font-weight: 700; }
.case2 { font-weight: bold; }
```

I am asking if when you define `@font-face` with numeric value eg `700` (or vice versa) and then use its quivalent somewhere in CSS (at this case `bold`) some browsers could use faux bold text instead of the one defined via @font-face.

*Thank you experts!*

Comment: The answer to the title is "No", but then I saw that you used "eg" in the question body, and that makes for a totally different question! Indeed, there are some circumstances under which `font-weight:600` will render as semi-bold for fonts that don't have a native 600 weight built in..

Comment: Also, there is no difference between webfonts and local fonts in this respect. If you find that there is, using a webfont, I would look at connectivity problems, CORS, caching issues maybe.

Comment: So basically what I'm asking is if there is really no difference between 700 and bold at all.

Comment: I don't know what kind of proof you expect. https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/ says "All of the text of this specification is normative", is that evidence enough?

Comment: I guess so. I'm glad that thinks are the same as I know them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no difference between them. Maybe using it like `font-weight:bold` makes your code more readable than using `font-weight:700`.

You can also use another values about `font-weight`.

1. 100 - Thin
2. 200 - Extra Light (Ultra Light)
3. 300 - Light
4. 400 - Normal
5. 500 - Medium
6. 600 - Semi Bold
7. 700 - Bold
8. 800 - Extra Bold (Ultra Bold)
9. 900 - Black (Heavy)

'`font-weight:normal`' is synonymous with '`font-weight:400`', and '`font-weight:bold`' is synonymous with '`font-weight:700`'.

Comment: I added an example, could you please check if there really is no difference in such case? Thanks.

Comment: I know the table you provided. I was asking if when you define @font-face with numeric value eg `700` (or vice versa) and then use its quivalent here `bold` some browsers could use faux bold text instead of the one defined via @font-face.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC some fonts support multiple level of boldness but some don't,
so if a font support the feature there would be a subtle difference but otherwise both look the same and bold.